# MLE in a stable Gaussian VAR$(p)$ process. Are the Lutkepohl formulas correct?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, vector-autoregression

In «New Introduction to Multiple Time Series», page 90, we have the following formulas for the ML estimators of a stable Gaussian VAR$(p)$ process:

[image]

where $\tilde \alpha = vec(\tilde A_1,...,\tilde A_p)$.

And here is exactly where my doubt resides. If for $\tilde \alpha$ estimator, I need $\tilde \mu$ estimator, but then for $\tilde \mu$ I'm going to need also $\tilde \alpha$. So, how is this dependence broken, or is this solved by an iterative algorithm that will reach a fixed point?

Comment: (3.4.9) contains $\tilde\mu$ while (3.4.10) contains $\tilde\mu^*$. Aren't they different?

Comment: @RichardHardy The only difference is their dimension. With $\mu^*$  is $T K \times 1$, the other is $Kp\times 1$. $T$ is the sample size, $K$ the dim of vector autoregression and $p$ the order of the vector autoregression. Both have the same element $\mu$, the mean ($K$-dim vector) of the process, repeated accordingly.